# is there a way to know who initiated a send using the Ampscript functions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can we know who initiated a send using the Ampscript functions?

Comment: From a landing/microsite page?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_Job` [**System Data View**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_job/) contains the `AccountUserID` of the person that initiated the send.

So if you know the `JobID`, you use the [**LookupRows()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookuprows/) AMPScript function on `_Job` to retrieve it the user for a particular send.